# How to change the value of cells in a pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV that I want to edit in Pandas. He has such columns:

```
P-N,U-N,I,R,C,I-L,L-D,RS,em,D,l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5,l_6,l_7,l_8,l_9,l_10,l_11,l_12,l_13,l_14,l_15,l_16,l_17,l_18
```

Example:

```
TEXT,TEXT,https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/11/46/8b/11468ba5-05a1-6b61-56e8-9389416c3fed/mza_8280916651621281968.jpg/268x0w.jpg,6,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/alav-el-pinche-podcast/id1459010039,Aug 1 2019,https://feed.podbean.com/alav/feed.xml,quinonescristian@yahoo.com,TEXT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
TEXT,TEXT,https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/9c/3c/5d/9c3c5dd7-049c-0a36-51a5-146a6b67c032/mza_2227232542399366991.png/268x0w.jpg,22,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/couple-goals-with-s-m/id1354222194,18 Aug 2019,https://couplegoals.podbean.com/feed.xml,No email,TEXT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
TEXT,TEXT,https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/19/99/2a/19992a8a-c302-6416-27d2-78d4a751ff2d/mza_8707044730009010204.jpg/268x0w.jpg,1053,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/all-crime-no-cattle/id1327729036,Jul 26 2019,https://www.spreaker.com/show/3202978/episodes/feed,allcrimenocattle@gmail.com,TEXT",https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1207505792,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1298179135,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1255329049,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1256792057,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1250294822,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1317929691,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1328036628,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1244309070,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1377988275,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1214679007,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1166399817,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1242028887,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1184429621,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1289005078,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1396717244,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1259478351,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1295887970,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1278924392
TEXT,TEXT,https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/30/b6/46/30b6469c-0e15-e3d3-4063-6207d8020824/mza_1356338398462313394.jpg/268x0w.jpg,1186,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/extraterrestrial/id1449220604,Aug 13 2019,https://feeds.megaphone.fm/extraterrestrial,support@parcast.com,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1156724104,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1441968144,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1441824608,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1449997236,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1440306805,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1434465245,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1437682381,https://podcasts.applcom/us/podcast/id1441348407,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1449762156,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1438804143,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1440107092,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1454411295,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1449191242,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1094490100,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1450027383,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1294529191,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1197087242,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1468956772
TEXT,TEXT,https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/06/9e/c7/069ec760-12cb-fdef-4b28-ac96cc649f3f/mza_1930766855883297019.jpg/268x0w.jpg,No rating,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/another-dead-man-walking/id1449476437,Nov 7 2018,https://www.spreaker.com/show/3287452/episodes/feed,radio@sky.uk,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1448403218,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1453587264,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1453829416,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1435009373,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1462249765,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1448205703,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1458485904,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1451783176,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1436485458,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1462332471,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1447656582,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1447037392,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1459952501,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1458931325,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1448556563,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1409087641,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1400426755,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1462323616
```

Expected result:

```
TEXT,TEXT,https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/11/46/8b/11468ba5-05a1-6b61-56e8-9389416c3fed/mza_8280916651621281968.jpg/268x0w.jpg,6,TEXT,id1459010039,Aug 1 2019,https://feed.podbean.com/alav/feed.xml,quinonescristian@yahoo.com,TEXT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
TEXT,TEXT,https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/9c/3c/5d/9c3c5dd7-049c-0a36-51a5-146a6b67c032/mza_2227232542399366991.png/268x0w.jpg,22,TEXT,id1354222194,18 Aug 2019,https://couplegoals.podbean.com/feed.xml,No email,TEXT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
TEXT,TEXT,https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/19/99/2a/19992a8a-c302-6416-27d2-78d4a751ff2d/mza_8707044730009010204.jpg/268x0w.jpg,1053,TEXT,id1327729036,Jul 26 2019,https://www.spreaker.com/show/3202978/episodes/feed,allcrimenocattle@gmail.com,TEXT",id1207505792,id1298179135,id1255329049,id1256792057,id1250294822,id1317929691,id1328036628,id1244309070,id1377988275,id1214679007,id1166399817,id1242028887,id1184429621,id1289005078,id1396717244,id1259478351,id1295887970,id1278924392
TEXT,TEXT,https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/30/b6/46/30b6469c-0e15-e3d3-4063-6207d8020824/mza_1356338398462313394.jpg/268x0w.jpg,1186,TEXT,id1449220604,Aug 13 2019,https://feeds.megaphone.fm/extraterrestrial,support@parcast.com,TEXT,id1156724104,id1441968144,id1441824608,id1449997236,id1440306805,id1434465245,id1437682381,id1441348407,id1449762156,id1438804143,id1440107092,id1454411295,id1449191242,id1094490100,id1450027383,id1294529191,id1197087242,id1468956772
TEXT,TEXT,https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/06/9e/c7/069ec760-12cb-fdef-4b28-ac96cc649f3f/mza_1930766855883297019.jpg/268x0w.jpg,No rating,TEXT,id1449476437,Nov 7 2018,https://www.spreaker.com/show/3287452/episodes/feed,radio@sky.uk,TEXT,id1448403218,id1453587264,id1453829416,id1435009373,id1462249765,id1448205703,id1458485904,id1451783176,id1436485458,id1462332471,id1447656582,id1447037392,id1459952501,id1458931325,id1448556563,id1409087641,id1400426755,id1462323616
```

Now I am editing it like this:

```py
for key, value in enumerate(df["I-L"]):
    df["I-L"][key] = value.split("/")[-1]

for ln in range(1, 19):
    for key, value in enumerate(df[f"l_{ln}"]):
        try:
            df[f"l_{ln}"][key] = value.split("/")[-1]
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

But I have very large files with approximately 500,000 entries each and this method is sooooooo slow.

How can I do it faster?

Comment: the `try except` is because you do not have / in every row ? Do you want to keep the part befre / only for `I-L` and all th `l_number` or all of the columns ?

Comment: Please can you can show some example data with fewer columns (just a  few rows and columns) . Also, please show the expected results

Comment: @BenoitDrogou now its because i have blank cells. and no i dont want to keep the part before /

Comment: @AndrewLavers updated

Comment: expected result and example are the same in your question

Comment: @BenoitDrogou https://c.imge.to/2019/08/29/vvCysw.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# sample data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
P-N,U-N,I,R,C,I-L,L-D,RS,em,D,l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5,l_6,l_7,l_8,l_9,l_10,l_11,l_12,l_13,l_14,l_15,l_16,l_17,l_18
TEXT,TEXT,https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/11/46/8b/11468ba5-05a1-6b61-56e8-9389416c3fed/mza_8280916651621281968.jpg/268x0w.jpg,6,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/alav-el-pinche-podcast/id1459010039,Aug 1 2019,https://feed.podbean.com/alav/feed.xml,quinonescristian@yahoo.com,TEXT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
TEXT,TEXT,https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/9c/3c/5d/9c3c5dd7-049c-0a36-51a5-146a6b67c032/mza_2227232542399366991.png/268x0w.jpg,22,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/couple-goals-with-s-m/id1354222194,18 Aug 2019,https://couplegoals.podbean.com/feed.xml,No email,TEXT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
TEXT,TEXT,https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/19/99/2a/19992a8a-c302-6416-27d2-78d4a751ff2d/mza_8707044730009010204.jpg/268x0w.jpg,1053,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/all-crime-no-cattle/id1327729036,Jul 26 2019,https://www.spreaker.com/show/3202978/episodes/feed,allcrimenocattle@gmail.com,TEXT",https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1207505792,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1298179135,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1255329049,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1256792057,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1250294822,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1317929691,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1328036628,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1244309070,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1377988275,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1214679007,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1166399817,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1242028887,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1184429621,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1289005078,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1396717244,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1259478351,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1295887970,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1278924392
TEXT,TEXT,https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/30/b6/46/30b6469c-0e15-e3d3-4063-6207d8020824/mza_1356338398462313394.jpg/268x0w.jpg,1186,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/extraterrestrial/id1449220604,Aug 13 2019,https://feeds.megaphone.fm/extraterrestrial,support@parcast.com,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1156724104,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1441968144,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1441824608,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1449997236,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1440306805,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1434465245,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1437682381,https://podcasts.applcom/us/podcast/id1441348407,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1449762156,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1438804143,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1440107092,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1454411295,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1449191242,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1094490100,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1450027383,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1294529191,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1197087242,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1468956772
TEXT,TEXT,https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts123/v4/06/9e/c7/069ec760-12cb-fdef-4b28-ac96cc649f3f/mza_1930766855883297019.jpg/268x0w.jpg,No rating,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/another-dead-man-walking/id1449476437,Nov 7 2018,https://www.spreaker.com/show/3287452/episodes/feed,radio@sky.uk,TEXT,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1448403218,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1453587264,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1453829416,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1435009373,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1462249765,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1448205703,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1458485904,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1451783176,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1436485458,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1462332471,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1447656582,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1447037392,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1459952501,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1458931325,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1448556563,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1409087641,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1400426755,https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id1462323616
"""))

# A function for splitting at last "/'
# with safety for null (NaN) values
def splitter(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return s.split("/")[-1]
    else:
        return s

# apply the splitter to each column
cols = ["I-L"] + [f"l_{ln}" for ln in range(1, 19)]
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(splitter)

# print a few
print(df[["I-L", "l_1", "l_2", "l_18"]])

#             I-L           l_1           l_2          l_18
# 0  id1459010039           NaN           NaN           NaN
# 1  id1354222194           NaN           NaN           NaN
# 2  id1327729036  id1207505792  id1298179135  id1278924392
# 3  id1449220604  id1156724104  id1441968144  id1468956772
# 4  id1449476437  id1448403218  id1453587264  id1462323616
```